# Write a different XMLs for android device with and without navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I am currently developing an android game and I was wondering: how can I make a different XML layout for devices with navigation bar and without navigation bar? I want to position some buttons on bottom and, depending wether the device has or not navigation bars, the buttons should be higher/lower...

Comment: Most games will [hide the navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html), perhaps you want to as well to give a consistent gaming experience?

Comment: I don't really understand why would you want to position the buttons differently. If there is no navigation bar, there are usually in the same distance from your window hardware buttons which can be pretty sensitive as well so the possibility to (mis)press a button is about the same.

Comment: yea, the thing is that they are not: there's a huge space in the bottom where the navigation bar should appear...